# Undefined reference to defined static private variable

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, static-members

i've got a problem dealing with static private variables. Here is my code.

ClassA.h:

```
class ClassA{
    static int a;
public:
    int getA();
};
```

Class.cpp:

```
#include "ClassA.h"

int ClassA::a = 9001;

int ClassA::getA(){
    return a; //<--- Undefined reference to ClassA::a
}
```

As you can see, i defined the static variable in the implementation file, as it has been said over and over, i also did this to other static member of other classes, and they work without any problem, but this one doesn't. Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it. Check the semicolon as Madsen suggested, nothing more.

Comment: Sorry, my fault for forgetting the semicolon

Comment: This code is fine. There must be some other detail in your actual code that you've overlooked.

Comment: VTC as not reproducible

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ClassA is missing a `;` at the end of its declaration?

I can't spot any errors in the code you've provided. Perhaps ClassA is defined inside a namespace?

Answer (score -2):

declare

int ClassA::a; in .h itself

as below:

```
class ClassA{
    static int a;
public:
    int getA();
};
int ClassA::a = 9001;
```

Also, Your class A declaration does not end with a semicolon.

Comment: added the semicolon at the end of Class A declaration?

Comment: Yes, it was an error in my trascription of the code, it was already there in the .h file in my computer.

Comment: Not to me, maybe because i'm using Eclipse C++, but the error remains.

Comment: Defining it in the header is a bad idea, because if two units include that header then the behaviour is undefined.